# dbcontext BeforeSaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In our ApplicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync we have a BeforeSaveChanges method in which we'd like to do the following:

We need a cached list of records which contains the names of certain entities. For these entities we will do an additional check in BeforeSaveChanges. This list will be managed in the UI.

FYI: we're using Mediatr, EF Core, CQRS.

How would you handle this? Any code examples?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are many questions (and answers) on overriding `SaveChanges(Async)` and doing "something" with entities in the change tracker. Maybe you should try to find an appropriate one. Your description is too vague to help you.

Comment: Hmm, I thought the question was clear that in the BeforeSaveChanges method we need a cached list of records. These records will hold the names of entities. It is for these entities that we need to do 'something' in the BeforeSaveChanges method. The 'something' is not relevant. I just have no idea how the ApplicationDbContext can have a cached list of these records.